# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Windows Authentication keeps prompting for credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I'm trying to setup an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API with Windows Authentication in IIS 8.5.

I've been following the steps [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) on MSDN. We're using the Kestrel engine in combination with Kerberos. So we additonally [set up the SPNs and added Negotiate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Now, when I try to logon using my credentials I just get prompted for them again.
In the Event Viewer I can see multiple events in Security, stating "Audit Success" for that user at the moments I attempted to login.

Nothing shows up in the IIS logs and I'm not able to hit any breakpoints.
Would anyone happen to know where to go from here?

Comment: Please check your username and password is right or not and be sure that give Authenticated users read access to content folder.

Comment: The username/password combination is correct, hence the "Audit Success". When I try with different credentials it will give an "Audit Failure" in the Event Log. Everyone is added as group with read access on the complete root folder and subfolders. Still prompting for credentials.

Comment: It seems to be a loop-back issue on the server itself. When we access it from another client, all is okay.